# How to write %~dp0 into a batch file created by a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cd

My program is generating batch files. But when it writes `%~dp0` into the new file, it just writes the location of the generator program.

Is there any possibility to write `%~dp0` into an new batch file?

My code looks like this:

```
echo cd %~dp0>>Newfile.bat
```

The batch generator should write `cd %~dp0` into the new file, but it writes this:

```
cd C:\Batch files\Bat file Generator\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 >>newfile.txt echo cd %%~dp0
```

Since `%` has a special meaning to `cmd`, it needs to be "escaped" by a preceding character. The `escape` character for most symbols with a special meaning is caret `^` but for `%` is `%`.

Putting a redirector directly after a digit is asking for trouble...

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day! :D

Answer (score 2):

Just like this should do!

```bat
Echo CD/D "%%~dp0">>Newfile.bat
```